# Design Issue (Unity, Reflection)

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, office-addins

I am currently developing a Microsoft Word Add-In that communicates with a backend via webservices. The dialogs in this Add-In are created with WPF and I make use of the MVVM pattern. The viewmodels communicate with the repository over services. In order to decouple viewmodel and services I use the DI-container framework Unity.
There is some kind of state (I call it "Context", similar to the http-context) that depends on the active document at the time a window/viewModel was created. This context contains stuff like the active user. 
Since a picture is worth more than a thousand words, I prepared a [diagram](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eikcqvztlh5tkju/Architectural%20Overview%20%28ActiveContext%29.png?dl=0) to illustrate the design.

Now my problem is, that when a service method is called, the service needs to know what the active context is in order to process the request.

---

**At the moment** I am avoiding this problem by having one service for each document. But since this cuts across the statelessness of services, I don't consider it as a durable solution.

---

**I also considered** passing the context to the viewModel, so that I can pass it back to the service when calling a method there. But I see three problems here:

*Technical Problems*:

- Each time I want to resolve a Window with Unity I would have to pass a ParameterOverride-object with the context - what creates dependencies to the concrete viewModel implementation.
  *=> Or is there a better way to achieve this with unity?*

*Cosmetical Problems*:

- I would have to pass the Context as object since the class for it is part of the startup-project and the ViewModels are not. When I now want to obtain data from the context, I'd have to cast it.
- Consider a windowViewModel that contains data for a TreeView with hundreds of TreeViewItems. I would have to pass the Context to each of these "TreeItemViewModels" if I'd want to call a service-method in one of these.

---

So I'm wondering if there is a way of automatically "injecting" (maybe reflection?) the context into the viewModel at runtime without the viewModel knowing anything about it. This is probably impossible to achieve with Unity, but I'm always open to being convinced.
On the other side, when a method on a service is called, the injected context is automatically extracted (maybe by some kind of layer in front the actual service) and saved into some globally accessible property.

I hope that some of you can help me. I appreciate any kind of idea.

Comment: Using Unity just to *decouple viewmodel and services* seems like an extraordinary amount of overkill to me. All you need is an interface to do that at its simplest level. It also seems to me that without using Unity, your problems would simply go away.

Comment: Hi Sheridan, thanks for your answer. I don't just use Unity for decoupling. Other reasons are for example clean code (excpet for the problem described above, of course) or easy replaceability of the services (e.g. for a test configuration). But I do not insist on using Unity. Just wanted to give it a try. I already thought about using the Abstract Factory Pattern instead. But then the viewmodels would still need a property for the Context and casting would also be necessary to read it. So I still prefere another solution.